# How to configure Jackson for HTTP REST response body in Spring

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to build a REST service using Spring 4.3.4 and Spring Boot 1.4.2. What I need to do is to configure the Jackson instance in such a way that I can access the actual configuration of the object mapper (e.g. use fields only, don't use getter/setter methods etc).

After a long session of debugging Spring code, I tried all of the following:

- `@Bean` for Jackson2ObjectMapper
- `@Bean` for Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
- `@Bean` for Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean

None of the above had any effect. Ultimately, I think I've figured out the root cause of it all. Here's how Spring ***really*** creates it's Jackson instances:

- `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter` calls `new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()`...
- ... which builds a new `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`...
- ...via static method `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()`

ALL of the above is `static` (!!) and completely neglects any kind of configuration, regardless whether it's XML, Java `@Configuration` classes or even `application.properties`.

**The question is:** do I need to implement my own converter that replaces the `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter` (is that even possible?), or is there any other solution to configure the Jackson instance?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: We tried all day to do it the way described in the manual. It just won't work that way, the configuration is ignored by the Spring source code. RTFM is not very helpful in this case...

Comment: Have you added the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to your config? Because if you have, that disables the Spring boot support/customization for MVC. So remove it if it's present. Otherwise, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Yes we do have the @EnableWebMvc annotation active. Basically we "fixed" the problem by implementing a configuration adapter and modifying the message converters. We replaced the AllEncompassingHttpMessageConverter with our own implementation that did the exactly same thing, except with our own Jackson config. It might not be the prettiest solution, but it works. My confidence in Spring Boot configuration however is shaken once more.

Comment: I repeat. You must NOT have EnableWebMvc. Remove it, and everything should work much better.

Comment: I run into a very similar problem for my application which uses Spring HATEOAS. I created a special annotation for my data beans and a Jackson custom deserializer that requires injection of the info from annotations by the application context.  I use the SpringHandlerInstantiator to perform this injection.However, when deployed the AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter is created statically and thus does not leverage the  SpringHandlerInstantiator. Very frustrating to find the work around.  @Alan47 Would you mind to share you trick with your replacement of AllEncompassingHttpMessageConverter

Comment: @fellahst First of all, we defined our Jackson `ObjectMapper` as a `@Bean`. Then, we copied the source code of `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter` into a new class and attached `@Component` to it. In the source code of this class, we `@Autowired` our `ObjectMapper` and replaced all calls to `new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()` with `new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(this.objectMapper)`.

Comment: As the final step, we had to get our custom implementation of `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter` into the system. For this purpose, we extended `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`with `@Configuration` attached, and created an override for the `extendMessageConverters` method. In there, we iterate over the list of converters, and if we encounter an `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter`, we replace it with our custom implementation. We also replace the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with one that uses our `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Thanks @Alan47. Will give it a try !